# Angular.js Two Digest() Sucessions Clashing

Tags: angularjs

I have this function:

```
function scopeMutateSuccess(modalInstance, state) {
    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
      modalEventConfig.statusType = 'success';
      modalEventConfig.nodeStatus = 'Completed Successfully';
    });
}
```

In the call stack...there a is a `digest()` that is called before this function. However, it is still running while this function gets called and I get a digest() already in progress. I need my own `digest()` in this function or otherwise the view does not get updated with the scope member values. The first `digest()` is being called somewhere else and not by me so I can't controller it firing.

Is there a event listener for when a `digest()` ends or a way to keep them from clashing?

Comment: Why are you doing `$rootScope.$apply()` ? Anyhow take a look at this https://github.com/yearofmoo/AngularJS-Scope.SafeApply/blob/master/src/Scope.SafeApply.js

Comment: because this is in a service which doesn't use local scopes.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Definitely mostly this is design problem because of which you end up invoking the digest cycle manually..

Comment: I don't see this as a design problem since my service is reusable and it is the appropriate place for logic and model data(such as primitive scope members). Simply, I need a digest when the scope members are mutated or the view does not reflect the change.

Comment: _"Simply, I need a digest when the scope members are mutated or the view does not reflect the chang"_ This is a huge code smell for me.. If your service is out of angular, you could wrap it in angular and make use of angular `$q` which will manage digest cycle. Or just try using `$timeout` instead of rootscope and see(though i will try not to do that).

Comment: You should always trigger the digest from the root of the stack, namely when an event occurs, like a user click or a resolved xhr request. Understanding the stacktrace is fundamental to understand angular digests.

Comment: @PSL what is the code smell about using a service for logic and storing scope data? This is the convention I have been told to use many times. I didn't want to go the `$timeout`(which $q uses) route if possible.

Comment: @dman storing data and triggering a digest are not the same thing. If you want to trigger a digest that's because there is an event which happens 'outside' angular. Unfortunately, If that event didn't trigger a digest you'll find yourself triggering it down the stack which is bad..

Comment: @dman i dont know about that, i have not even seen that code piece of yours, however it is a code smell when you have to manually invoke a digest cycle (especially in a piece of code block which has no idea why it is doing that ), unless you are inside a directive which does dom manipulation (through a non angular plugin or something or your own cutom functionality) and you have some events being bound which updates scope variable.

Comment: @Ilan Frumer How would I trigger a digest at the root of the stack since `xhr.onreadystatechange` in angular.js is at the root and I do not have access to that?

Comment: @dman If you use $http it automatically triggers the digest for you.

Comment: @Ilan Frumer using restangular and when it's promise is resolved, there is function that is called to mutate the scope member to `modalEventConfig.statusType = 'success';`. This is why I need apply() to make the view reflect the change.

Comment: @dman You probably got it wrong. Just remove the $apply and it would all work just fine. you don't really need to manually trigger $apply each time you change something on the scope, only be sure that the event on top of the stack triggers it. All the angular built-in services (and Restangular also) already trigger $digest for you. good luck

Comment: no, without my $apply() the view doesn't reflect scope data change because the digest kicked off before the scope data change.

Comment: @dman please create a plunker so we can see the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can always check for digest in progress using `$scope.$$phase` (returns true if it's in progress).

However, the simplest fix here seems to be just to wrap the inside function into a $timeout callback (which takes care of the in-progress issue for you), like this:

```
function scopeMutateSuccess(modalInstance, state) {
    $timeout(function() {
      modalEventConfig.statusType = 'success';
      modalEventConfig.nodeStatus = 'Completed Successfully';
    }, 0);
}
```

Make sure you inject the $timeout dependency, of course.

Comment: Normally this would work, but after much trouble shooting my issue goes further than this...so, I will have to make a new post since the root problem is something else.